# Encoding with spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, encoding

I am using Spring MVC to handle my request and I need to send an String to do a search. I am sending, for example, `Caçapava`, but somewhere it was converting to this `CaÃ§apva`, everywhere I was looking for my encoding is set to `UTF-8`. I am using `Jackson` to handle my JSON and `ExtJs` to build my view. My request is ok, so the problem is not with my `ExtJs` request.

Request parameters:

`Query String Parameters`

`_dc:1363866108143`

`nomeCidade:Caçapava`

`page:1`

`start:0`

`limit:50`

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I use [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) to force Spring to use UTF-8 (`web.xml`):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But, it may also depend on your server. [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) is the discussion for tomcat. And see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) for `URIEncoding` parameter.